# (Python) I have fundamental misunderstandings which I am trying to address. Can somebody help, via the following "left rotation" example?

Tags: python, arrays, syntax, rotation, runtime-error

I am a novice programmer and I feel that I have very fundamental misunderstandings which I am trying to identify. In this question, I am going to be working out my logic to a coding challenge in order to help you identify the misconceptions I am experiencing. The context of this question is the Hackerrank Interview Kit problem "Left Rotation". https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-array-left-rotation/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

It says the following in regards to the input format:

The first line contains two space-separated integers *n* and *d*, the size of *a* and the number of left rotations.
The second line contains  space-separated integers, each an *a*[i].

Then it gives an example input:

5 4

1 2 3 4 5

My approach to this problem:

What I want is to create 2 loops. One loop to repeat the following process *d* times, (ie. 4 times), and a nested loop that goes through the whole second input string (1 2 3 4 5), and does the following:

1. sets the value of the first index (ie: 1) of the second input string (ie: 1 2 3 4 5) to a variable called *temp*. (I was thinking the line of code that does this would look something like this: *temp* = *a*[1]. But is this correct syntactically? Can i do this? Because will python recognize 1 2 3 4 5 as an array automatically, or do I have to convert this second input line from a string to an array, first?)
2. Next, for every index of the second input line EXCEPT for the last, change the value of that index to equal the value of the next index in the sequence. So, *a*[1] = 2, *a*[2] = 3, *a*[3] = 4, and *a*[4] = 5. My logic is that at the end of this step, the line should now be this: 2 3 4 5 5. (I was thinking the line of code that does this would look something like this:

for *i* in len(*a*-1):

*i* = [*i* + 1].

(Is this correct syntactically? I feel like there is something wrong with this line, but I am not sure what it is.)

3. Set the last index of the array to the temp value. (I was thinking the line of code that does this would be the following: *a*[*n*] = *temp*. Again, unsure about my syntax. By my logic, I would imagine that the input line now looks like this: 2 3 4 5 1. (Also, how does python know what *n*: is? I understand that the first input line is in the format *n,d*, but how does *python* know what those variables stand for? How do I tell it?)
4. This process happens *d* times. So the final result to return once the loop finishes would be the rotated array, which would be: 5 1 2 3 4. But I am even confused on how to write the line for the return statement.

With this logic in mind, here is my code:

```
def rotLeft(a, d):

    i = 0

    newArr = []

    for i in range (d):
        
        temp = a[1]
                 
        for i in len(a-1):
            
            i = [i + 1]

            a[n] = temp

            a = newArr

    return newArr
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    first_multiple_input = input().rstrip().split()

    n = int(first_multiple_input[0])

    d = int(first_multiple_input[1])

    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    result = rotLeft(a, d)

    fptr.write(' '.join(map(str, result)))
    fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

I am getting a runtime error, which I know can be caused by a number of things.

Overall, I am wondering if someone can help me identify any places where I am going wrong in my syntax or logic. I think one of my main points of confusion is the relationship between the input strings and the values being passed into the function. Any contributions are severely appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you find yourself stuck it's never a bad idea to step back and go to the basics.

I suggest starting your problem by writing down a few of the possible cases on paper and trying to spot patterns, before you write ANY code.

Write your code in iterations, starting with something very simple and slowly work towards your end goal.

Loop through the existing array, adding it's elements to the newlist at the original  elements index plus the shift amount, then apply modulus of the length of the original list to have it 'wrap' around.

[Here's a helpful link](https://blog.mattclemente.com/2019/07/12/modulus-operator-modulo-operation/#:%7E:text=The%20modulus%20operator%20%2D%20or%20more,returns%20the%20whole%20number%20remainder.) if you aren't sure how modulus works

```
def rotLeft(a, d):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        new_list.append(a[(i+d) % len(a)]);
    
    return new_list
```

Comment: I think there's a bug in this program -- the rotation is to the left, not to the right, so the index should be `(i - d + len(a)) % len(a)`.

Comment: Right but, respectfully, I did write the problem down, and it seemed to make logical sense to me based on my reasoning on paper, @EwanBrown, which is why I feel the most concerned. Can you help me to understand where I am going wrong in my problem solving then? Perhaps it would help if I shared my notes with you, i will attach them in more comments...

Comment: @EwanBrown, I have put my notes into the following pdf. Perhaps you can have a look and tell me where I am not making sense? file:///Users/sofiabianchi/Downloads/IMG_0003-merged.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of syntax errors, but HackerRank likely wouldn't accept an approach where you'd perform one left rotation at a time. (The input size is too big for your algorithm to handle in a small amount of time. If you're just starting to program, don't worry too much about what this means; Ewan Brown is right that correctness is infinitely more important than efficiency. This is solely meant to serve as an explanation to motivate why I'm giving a different approach as opposed to debugging the one you've laid out.)

Instead, what you should do is create a new array that rotates an element by `d` (since you know the offset in advance). This is faster: in essence, you'd be performing the left rotation for each element all at once, rather than over many steps.

```py
def rotLeft(a, d):
    result = [0] * len(a)
    for index, element in enumerate(a):
        result[((index - d) + len(a)) % len(a)] = element
    return result
```

Comment: I don't think he's looking for performance tips, and regardless a beginner should probably focus on problem solving skills and familiarization with a programming language rather than optimization.

Comment: I agree, but the existing approach wouldn't work even if you did fix the syntax errors. You're right that the runtime analysis is overkill; I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @EwanBrown Revised. Let me know your thoughts on the revised answer. The explanation is a bit more informal, but it should be less technically dense.

Comment: looks great to me!

Comment: Wow, EwanBrown and @BrokenBenchmark, I really couldn't thank you enough. Seeing the solutions you've provided, I can see why they work. But what I don't see is why my logic doesn't work. I can see what you're saying about not doing one left rotation at a time.

Comment: But I still don't understand why my problem solving approach wouldn't solve the problem eventually, even if the runtime is not ideal. Where do I go wrong? Could either of you mind taking another look at what I wrote to find places where I made mistakes in my thinking process? And same thing about syntax- in this example I've provided, would you mind breaking down some of the syntax errors you do see, and explaining why they are syntactically incorrect? (For instance, knowing the difference between an index and the value at that particular index, accidentally treating a string as an array, ect)

Comment: @EwanBrown, if you wouldn't mind, could you offer any help there too, if possible?

Comment: Again, Ewan and @BrokenBenchmark, here are my notes on paper for perhaps a better visual representation of my thought process. The algorithm I had there seemed to work in my head and on the paper. Why then, am I having such a hard time translating it to code? If it isn'y purely syntax, what else am I doing wrong? file:///Users/sofiabianchi/Downloads/IMG_0003-merged.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Ewan Brown nailed it. For completeness, I'll add an even more concise implementation using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```py
from itertools import cycle, islice

def rotLeft(a, d):
     return islice(cycle(a), d, len(a)+d)
```

[cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)  is a functional and abstract way to express the idea of "wrapping around" a collection.